# Keep getting 'undefined method error' user_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I am using devise in an app and I keep getting an undefined method error saying user_url. Here is what I have please help me solve this

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError in Users::SessionsController#create
undefined method `user_url' for #<Users::SessionsController:0xa33291c>

Rails.root: /home/vagrant/code/AppSample

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:159:in `url_for'
actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:101:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
...
```

Here is the User session_controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController <
Devise::SessionsController

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    @tenants_dashboard_path
  end


  def create
    user = User.find_by(:email => params[:email])
    manager = Manager.find_by(:email => (params[:email])
    if user && tenant.authenticate (params[:password])
      session[:tenant_id] = tenant.id
      redirect_to users_main_url, notice: "You are Logged in!"
    elsif
    manager && manager.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:manager_id] = manager.id
      return managers_main_url, notice: "You are Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid."
    end
end
```

The error is when I try to redirect my user to a dashboard page. Here is the after sign in method in my app controller

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(Users)
      return users_dashboard_path, notice: "You are Logged in!"
    elsif resource.is_a?(Managers)
      return managers_dashboard_path, notice: "You are Logged in!"
    end
  end
```

Here is the route:

```
    devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }
    devise_for :managers, controllers: {registrations: "managers/registrations", sessions: "managers/sessions" }
    resources :reports
    resource :dashboard

  get "/managers/why_use_us" => "managers/landing#index", as: :managers_why
  get "/users/why_choose_us" => "users/landing#index", as: :tenants_why

  get "/managers/LeaseDefend_dashboard" => "managers/dashboard#index", as: :managers_main
  get "/users/LeaseDefend_dashboard" => "users/dashboard#index", as: :tenants_main

  namespace :users do
    get 'landing', to: 'landing#index'
    get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
    resources :landing, :dashboard
  end''
```

I can't figure out what to change I changed the resource to match the name of the user folders i.e Managers & Tenants

Comment: from everything i see i have tenants_url but the site keeps saying tenant_url and I don't see anywhere to change it

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error?

Comment: Did you recreate the sessions controller? Check your redirects in there. The error specifically says tenant_url in your sessions controller.

Comment: I actually created two controllers the devise session controller and then a specific tenant session controller no matter which one i use (the devise or the tenant specific), both give the same error even though the devise session controller is bare

Comment: Got it! I changed the after_sign_in_path method and put an individual method in each controller since there are different users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the after_sign_in_path method and put an individual method in each controller since there are different user